# Using addKeyListener to bind keys Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, keydown

I'm making a small game for a class and I am having trouble finding a way to bind keys to functions. One solution I found was using addEventListener, however I cannot find a way to take the key value and bind it to an animation.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
if(event.which === 65) {
    $("#player").animate({left: '5px'});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = event.which || event.keyCode;  // Use either which or keyCode, depending on browser support
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in jQuery way.

```
  jsfiddle.net/jpmvkqzh/
```

position.left of element keep increasing 5px when user pressing right arrow key and deceasing 5px when user pressing left arrow key.

[.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) is to stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.